# Automatic replace in questions

Tags: discussion

Would it be possible to set automatic replace for some certain words in questions?

For example:

1. "Arduino" is a name and should start with a capitalized letter, there are no
   exceptions to that.
2. " , " should be replaced with ", " because there are no cases where
   there should be a space before a comma (or "?", "!" and ".").
3. Names of boards like "Arduino UNO" should fix themselves
   automatically.
4. Double and triple exclamation marks and question marks also could be
   auto-replaced.

If this was possible I think it would make the questions and answers more consistent and right saving some work to adjust those posts.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really like auto-fixups. There are times when they drive you insane. You may overlook borderline cases. For example:

> " , " should be replaced with ", " because there are no cases where there should be a space before a comma

Maybe in some comma-delimited file:

```
1234,  , , 5678
```

---

> Double and triple exclamation marks and question marks also could be auto-replaced.

How about:

> I tried to upload code to my Mega, but found it wouldn't upload when I had "!!!" in it:
>
> ```
>      Serial.println ("Furnace too hot!!!");
> ```

---

> Names of boards like "Arduino UNO" should fix themselves automatically.

Posts like your question would become impossible because you wouldn't be able to express the words "Arduino UNO". For example, you may be wanting to explain that UNO is the wrong capitalization to someone.

For example, what if someone posts "How come you corrected my spelling to Uno when it has UNO printed on the board?".

Comment: Everything in the quote, link and code tags could be ignored. The replacing should be really specific. Like only capitalising Arduino, Arduino model name first letter. The filters can be made really safe and I am quite sure the amount of errors reduced would be greater than the amount of errors created.